# my json webservice produces slashes unwantedly

Tags: php, database, json, web-services, cakephp

For some strange reason my cakephp webservice produces unwanted slashes only in the the part where i've stored weblinks. I use `json_encode();`to get my JSON data parsed. I edited my model conroller to get the filepath of my images stored in my DB.

```
My MODEL CONTROLLER CODE:
function beforeSave($options) {
if (!empty($this->data['Image']['name'])) {
    $this->data['Image']['plaatsfoto'] = "file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/tut_blog/app/webroot/img/uploads/images/"."".$this->data['Image']  ['img_file'].$this->dateFormatBeforeSave($this->data['Image']['name']);

}
return true;} 


 My JSON VIEW CODE:
  {
  "Image":{
     "id":"29",
     "gallery_id":"7",
     "name":"Dior",
     "img_file":"diosho_35n008vvc069biap.jpg",
     "plaatsfoto":"http:\/\/localhost\/tut_blog\/img\/uploads\/images\/data[Image][img_file]"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

`"http:\/\/localhost\/tut_blog\/img\/uploads\/images\/data[Image][img_file]"` is a valid JSON encoded string. The escapes are part of the JSON spec. This is how it's supposed to be.

If you `json_decode()` (PHP) it or `json.parse()` (JS) they will be removed for you.